# Add NSUnderlineStyle.PatternDash to NSAttributedString in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm trying to add an underline to some text in my Swift app. This is the code I have currently:

```
let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.currentHome.name)

let attrs = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.PatternDash]

text.addAttributes(attrs, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
homeLabel.attributedText = text
```

But I get this error on the `text.addAttributes` line:

> `NSString` is not identical to `NSObject`

How can I add an attribute contained in an enum to an NSMutableAttributedString in Swift?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28054270/2303865

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here's a full example of creating a `UILabel` with underlined text:

**Swift 5:**

```
let homeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))

let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello, world!")

let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.patternDash.rawValue | NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]

text.addAttributes(attrs, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length))

homeLabel.attributedText = text
```

---

**Swift 4:**

```
let homeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))

let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello, world!")

let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.patternDash.rawValue | NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]

text.addAttributes(attrs, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length))

homeLabel.attributedText = text
```

---

**Swift 2:**

Swift allows you to pass an `Int` to a method that takes an `NSNumber`, so you can make this a little cleaner by removing the conversion to `NSNumber`:

```
text.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleDouble.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
```

Note:  This answer previously used `toRaw()` as used in the original question, but that is now incorrect as `toRaw()` has been replaced by the property `rawValue` as of Xcode 6.1.

Comment: can you please, update your code with swift4 syntax.

Comment: Value of type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'addAttributes';

Comment: @BenShabat, you should an `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Answer (score 14):

If you want an actual dashed line, you should OR | the raw values of both PatternDash and StyleSingle enums like below:

```
let dashed     =  NSUnderlineStyle.PatternDash.rawValue | NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue

let attribs    = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : dashed, NSUnderlineColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()];

let attrString =  NSAttributedString(string: plainText, attributes: attribs)
```

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode 6.1, SDK iOS 8.1 `toRaw()` has been replaced by `rawValue`:

```
 text.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value:  NSUnderlineStyle.StyleDouble.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
```

Or Easier :

```
 var text : NSAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str, attributes : [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue])
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I needed the `toRaw()` method - this works:

```
text.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSNumber(integer:(NSUnderlineStyle.StyleDouble).toRaw()), range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
```