# How to use NSUnderlineStyle.PatternDot

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7, nsattributedstring

I am trying to use NSMutableAttributedString with dotted underline below is my code but none of the Patterns seem to work am I missing something ?

```
var str : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "HelloWorld")
        str.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName  , value: NSNumber(integer:(NSUnderlineStyle.PatternDot).rawValue), range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length))
```

Comment: Do you get a compiler error or wrong output or what? Here is a similar question, does that help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611716/add-nsunderlinestyle-patterndash-to-nsattributedstring-in-swift ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28053652/2477632

Comment: @Hamza it is not the same, in this case he has to combine the singleline with the paterndot

Comment: You should award the answer to the author below!

Answer (score 20):

You have to do it like this:

**Xcode 10 • Swift 4.2 or later**

```
yourLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World !!!", attributes: [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.patternDot.union(.single).rawValue])
```

Note: for older Swift syntax check edit history

Comment: I had to do this in Swifth "uStyle = NSUnderlineStyle(rawValue: NSUnderlineStyle.PatternDot.rawValue | NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue)" - I had a hard time figuring out how to "or" the two values :-)

Comment: @DavidH it works for me as it is using Swift 2.1.1 https://www.dropbox.com/s/xio2279u5if7oqk/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-13%20at%2020.35.28.png?dl=1

Comment: I'm curious why `rawValue` is necessary here.

Comment: rawValue is actually what the dictionary wants `[.underlineStyle: 1]` works whereas `[.underlineStyle:  .single]` does not