# How to underline a UILabel in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, uilabel, nsattributedstring

How to underline a `UILabel` in Swift? I searched the Objective-C ones but couldn't quite get them to work in Swift.

Comment: `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: whats with the dislikes? there is an obvious confusion here with the attibutes looking like method calls in objc

Comment: here You Can get the easy way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268060/adding-underline-attribute-to-partial-text-uilabel-in-storyboard/30750184#30750184

Comment: here are the easy way [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268060/adding-underline-attribute-to-partial-text-uilabel-in-storyboard/30750184#30750184][1]

Comment: Better solution algorithm with better solution you can look my answer     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053334/how-to-underline-a-uilabel-in-swift/65122584#65122584

Answer (score 314, accepted):

You can do this using [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring)

Example:

```
let underlineAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.thick.rawValue]
let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "StringWithUnderLine", attributes: underlineAttribute)
myLabel.attributedText = underlineAttributedString
```

**EDIT**

To have the same attributes for all texts of one UILabel, I suggest you to subclass UILabel and overriding text, like that:

**Swift 5**

*Same as Swift 4.2 but:* You should prefer the Swift initializer `NSRange` over the old `NSMakeRange`, you can shorten to `.underlineStyle` and linebreaks improve readibility for long method calls.

```swift
class UnderlinedLabel: UILabel {

override var text: String? {
    didSet {
        guard let text = text else { return }
        let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        attributedText.addAttribute(.underlineStyle,
                                    value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                    range: textRange)
        // Add other attributes if needed
        self.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
class UnderlinedLabel: UILabel {

override var text: String? {
    didSet {
        guard let text = text else { return }
        let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.count)
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle , value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: textRange)
        // Add other attributes if needed
        self.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
class UnderlinedLabel: UILabel {
    
    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            guard let text = text else { return }
            let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count)
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName , value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: textRange)
            // Add other attributes if needed
            self.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    }
}
```

And you put your text like this :

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UnderlinedLabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        label.text = "StringWithUnderLine"
    }
```

**OLD:**

*Swift (2.0 to 2.3):*

```
class UnderlinedLabel: UILabel {
    
    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            guard let text = text else { return }
            let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count)
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value:NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: textRange)
            // Add other attributes if needed
            
            self.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    }
}
```

*Swift 1.2:*

```
class UnderlinedLabel: UILabel {
    
    override var text: String! {
        didSet {
            let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, count(text))
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value:NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: textRange)
            // Add other attributes if needed
            
            self.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the best way to de-underline?

Comment: I've been wondering for a long time: why do we have to use rawValue otherwise it crashes?

Comment: You should pass `UTF16` count instead of the character count when creating your textRange `NSRange`

Comment: I've changed this solution to add a underlline on initialize, this way we can use it easily with storyboards

   `required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.addUnderline() // your code
    }`

Comment: Better solution algorithm with better solution you can look my answer     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053334/how-to-underline-a-uilabel-in-swift/65122584#65122584

Answer (score 128):

**Swift 5 & 4.2 one liner:**

```
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Text", attributes:
    [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
```

**Swift 4 one liner:**

```
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Text", attributes:
    [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])
```

**Swift 3 one liner:**

```
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Text", attributes:
      [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])
```

Comment: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue has been renamed to NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue in swift 4.2

Comment: How do I de-underline?

Comment: @N.Der Set again a normal text to label

Answer (score 31):

## **Swift 5:**

### 1- *Create* a String extension to get attributedText

```
extension String {

    var underLined: NSAttributedString {
        NSMutableAttributedString(string: self, attributes: [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
    }

}
```

### 2- *Use* it

On buttons:

```
<#YourButton#>.setAttributedTitle(<#YourButtonTitle#>.underLined, for: .normal)
```

On Labels:

```
<#YourLabel#>.attributedText = <#YourLabelTitle#>.underLined
```

**Or** [Stoyboard version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268060/adding-underline-attribute-to-partial-text-uilabel-in-storyboard/30750184#30750184)

Comment: The above extension worked out for me, thanks.

Answer (score 24):

If you are looking for a way to do this without inheritance:

#### Swift 5

```
extension UILabel {
    func underline() {
        if let textString = self.text {
          let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle,
                                          value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                          range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
          attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }
}
```

#### Swift 3/4

```
// in swift 4 - switch NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName with NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle
extension UILabel {
    func underline() {
        if let textString = self.text {
          let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
          attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
          attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }
}


extension UIButton {
  func underline() {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (self.titleLabel?.text!)!)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (self.titleLabel?.text!.characters.count)!))
    self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
  }
}
```

Comment: You should pass `UTF16` count instead of the character count when creating your `NSRange`

Answer (score 9):

Just a little fix for the Shlome answer in **Swift 4** and **Xcode 9**.

```
extension UILabel {
    func underline() {
        if let textString = self.text {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle,
                                          value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
                                          range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length - 1))
            attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }
}

    extension UIButton {
        func underline() {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (self.titleLabel?.text!)!)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle,
                                          value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
                                          range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (self.titleLabel?.text!.count)!))
            self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should pass `UTF16` count instead of the character count when creating your `NSRange`

Answer (score 7):

You can underline the `UILabel` text using Interface Builder.

Here is the link of my answer : [Adding underline attribute to partial text UILabel in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268060/adding-underline-attribute-to-partial-text-uilabel-in-storyboard/30750184#30750184)

Comment: This method fails if you rebind the text to the label.

Comment: @EricH What do you mean?

Answer (score 7):

Same Answer in **Swift 4.2**

For **UILable**

```
extension UILabel {
    func underline() {
        if let textString = self.text {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle,
                                          value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                          range: NSRange(location: 0, length: textString.count))
            self.attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }
}
```

Call for **UILabel** like below

```
myLable.underline()
```

For **UIButton**

```
extension UIButton {
    func underline() {
        if let textString = self.titleLabel?.text {

            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle,
                                          value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                          range: NSRange(location: 0, length: textString.count))
            self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
        }

    }
}
```

Call for **UIButton** like below

```
myButton.underline()
```

I looked into above answers and some of them are force unwrapping **text** value. I will suggest to get value by safely unwrapping. This will avoid crash in case of nil value.
Hope This helps :)

Comment: simply beutiful and easy

Comment: You should pass `UTF16` count instead of the character count when creating your `NSRange`

Comment: If you already have the extension for the UILabel, IMO it is simpler to call myButton.titleLabel?.underline(), or at least use it inside the underline() function in the extension for UIButton.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4, 4.2 and 5.**

```
  @IBOutlet weak var lblUnderLine: UILabel!
```

I need to underline particular text in UILabel. So, find range and set attributes.

```
    let strSignup = "Don't have account? SIGNUP NOW."
    let rangeSignUp = NSString(string: strSignup).range(of: "SIGNUP NOW.", options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
    let rangeFull = NSString(string: strSignup).range(of: strSignup, options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
    let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string:strSignup)
    attrStr.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                           NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)! as Any],range: rangeFull)
    attrStr.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                           NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)!,
                          NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.thick.rawValue as Any],range: rangeSignUp) // for swift 4 -> Change thick to styleThick
    lblUnderLine.attributedText = attrStr
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Underline to multiple strings in a sentence.**

```
extension UILabel {
    func underlineMyText(range1:String, range2:String) {
        if let textString = self.text {

            let str = NSString(string: textString)
            let firstRange = str.range(of: range1)
            let secRange = str.range(of: range2)
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: firstRange)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: secRange)
            attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }
}
```

**Use by this way.**

```
    lbl.text = "By continuing you agree to our Terms of Service and Privacy Policy."
    lbl.underlineMyText(range1: "Terms of Service", range2: "Privacy Policy.")
```

Comment: How you will track the touch?

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4** changes. 
Remeber to use **NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue** instead of **NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle**.

```
   'let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Testing")
    let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
    let underlinedMessage = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
    underlinedMessage.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle,
                                   value:NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
                                   range: textRange)
    label.attributedText = underlinedMessage
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this also if you want to achieve only half part of label as underline:-  //For Swift 4.0+

```
let attributesForUnderLine: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont(name: AppFont.sourceSansPro_Regular, size: 12) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
            .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]

        let attributesForNormalText: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont(name: AppFont.sourceSansPro_Regular, size: 12) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11),
            .foregroundColor: AppColors.ColorText_787878]

        let textToSet = "Want to change your preferences? Edit Now"
        let rangeOfUnderLine = (textToSet as NSString).range(of: "Edit Now")
        let rangeOfNormalText = (textToSet as NSString).range(of: "Want to change your preferences?")

        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textToSet)
        attributedText.addAttributes(attributesForUnderLine, range: rangeOfUnderLine)
        attributedText.addAttributes(attributesForNormalText, range: rangeOfNormalText)
        yourLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is causing an error in my build environment.

This doesn't work in Swift 4.0:

```
attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, 
                            value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, 
                            range: textRange)
```

Try this instead:

```
attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle,
                            value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
                            range: textRange)
```

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

// Swift 4 Version

```
 let attributedString  = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text Here", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle : true])

self.yourlabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 1):

A class to set and remove underline for UIbuttons for Swift 5. I hope this helps

```
import Foundation
   import UIKit

   class UiUtil {

       static let underlineThickness = 2
    
       class func removeUnderlineFromButton( _ button:UIButton ) {
          if let str = button.titleLabel?.attributedText {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString( attributedString: str )
            attributedString.removeAttribute(.underlineStyle, range: 
   NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
            button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
         }
      }

    class func setUnderlineFromButton( _ button:UIButton ) {
        if let str = button.titleLabel?.attributedText {
            let attributedStringUnderline = NSMutableAttributedString( attributedString: 
    str  )
              attributedStringUnderline.addAttribute(
                NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle,
                value: underlineThickness,
                range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedStringUnderline.length)
              )
              button.setAttributedTitle(attributedStringUnderline, for: .normal)
           }
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have algorithm that used in my app. In this algorithm you can underline substring even that have space between words

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString{

    static func  findSubStringAndUnderlineIt(subStringToBeFound : String,totalString : String)->  NSMutableAttributedString?{
        
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: totalString)

        var spaceCount = 0
        
        if subStringToBeFound.contains(" "){
            spaceCount = subStringToBeFound.components(separatedBy:" ").count-1
        }

        
        if  let range = attributedString.string.range(of: subStringToBeFound, options: .caseInsensitive){
        
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange((range.lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: subStringToBeFound)) ,(range.upperBound.utf16Offset(in: subStringToBeFound)) +
            spaceCount))
                return attributedString
        }
        return attributedString
        
    }
    
}
```

in used section

```
 lblWarning.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString.findSubStringAndUnderlineIt(subStringToBeFound:"Not: Sadece uygulamanın reklamları kaldırılacaktır.", totalString: lblWarning.text!)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 2.3

```
extension UIButton {
    func underline() {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (self.titleLabel?.text!)!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (self.titleLabel?.text!.characters.count)!))
        self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

and in ViewController

```
@IBOutlet var yourButton: UIButton!
```

in `ViewDidLoad` Method or in your function just write

```
yourButton.underline()
```

it will underline the title of your button