# Adding underline attribute to partial text UILabel in storyboard

Tags: ios, text, attributes, storyboard, uilabel

How can I underline partial text of `UILabel` using only storyboard? I am able to do this in code and I'm able to underline the entire text of a label, but not just one or two words in the string.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

1. select the `UILabel` and go to **Attribute Inspector** section.
   Change the text value from **plain** to **Attributed** .

   [image]
2. Select the particular part of text which you want to **Underline** .

   **Note**: If u want full text to be **Underline** select full text.

   [image]
3. Now right click and change the font to **Underline**.

   [image]

It will **Underline** the text

[image]

Comment: This answer works in iPhone 5s but does not show the underline in 6 and 6 plus devices. Is there any other way

Answer (score 2):

Steps:-

1. Go to TextEdit and create your UILabel text with underline.
2. Change UILabel text to Attributed (Attributed Selector).
3. Copy Underlined text and assign to UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Through code:

```
    func underLineText(text: String)-> NSMutableAttributedString
           let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
     attributedText.addAttribute(NSMutableAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length))
          return attributedText
        }
```

//calling of func

```
   yourLbl.attributedText = underLineText(text:yourLbl.text!)
```

List of other underline Types

```
 NSMutableAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
 NSMutableAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.thick.rawValue
 NSMutableAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.double.rawValue
 NSMutableAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.patternDot.rawValue
 NSMutableAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.patternDash.rawValue
 NSMutableAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.patternDashDot.rawValue
 NSMutableAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.patternDashDotDot.rawValue
 NSMutableAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.byWord.rawValue
```

Comment: Question is to apply, underline in the storyboard. For coding, we have answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053334/how-to-underline-a-uilabel-in-swift