# Unable to make some part of UILabel underline in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, range

I have a UILabel I want to make some part of it as underline. I am using below code for that. But it underline the whole label not the some part of label. Please tell me how can I make some part of label as Underline.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "UserAgreement".localized)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 10))

labelTc.attributedText = attributedString
```

I don't want to do with the storyboard

Comment: Follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268060/adding-underline-attribute-to-partial-text-uilabel-in-storyboard

Comment: You must read my question before suggestion. First i want to do it progrmatically. Second i have tried which does not solve my problem

Answer (score 5):

Try this

**Swift 4**

```
    let wholeStr = "Don't have an account? Register"
    //let rangeToUnderLine = (wholeStr as NSString).range(of: "Register")
    let rangeToUnderLine = NSRange(location: 0, length: 10))
    let underLineTxt = NSMutableAttributedString(string: wholeStr, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20),NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)])
    underLineTxt.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: rangeToUnderLine)
    labelTc.attributedText = underLineTxt
```

**Swift 3.2**

```
    let wholeStr = "Don't have an account? Register"
    //let rangeToUnderLine = (wholeStr as NSString).range(of: "Register")
    let rangeToUnderLine = NSRange(location: 0, length: 10))
    let underLineTxt = NSMutableAttributedString(string: wholeStr, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20),NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white])
    underLineTxt.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: rangeToUnderLine)
    labelTc.attributedText = underLineTxt
```

[image]

Comment: No such value exist as NSAttributedStringKey.font

Comment: Are you using swift 3 or swift 4?

Comment: Swift 4 i am using

Comment: There no such value as   NSAttributedStringKey.font

Comment: @DhirajKumar try `NSFontAttributeName`

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: Can you confirm your swift version by checking build settings?

Comment: I am using Swift 3.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159067/discussion-between-rajesh-and-dhiraj-kumar).

Comment: I've included answer for swift 3.2 also
pls check it