# underline part of uiLabel and link underlined section

Tags: ios, swift, click, uilabel

I'm new to iOS development.

I've got a label `LatestInfo` this has text and is meant to have a link to a website: e.g. `For the latest information visit example.com/latestInfo`

I want the display to underline the url `example.com/latestInfo` and make it clickable.

I am using Swift not Obejective-C

How can I go about doing this?

EDIT as per Pierre's request:

```
@IBOutlet weak var linkLabel: UITextView!
let string              = "A great link : Google"
let range               = (string as NSString).rangeOfString("Google")
let attributedString    = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)

attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: NSURL("http://www.google.fr")!, range: range)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSNumber(int: 1), range: range)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.orangeColor(), range: range)

linkLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: have a look at this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053334/how-to-underline-a-uilabel-in-swift) link

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look for NSMutableAttributedString and especially for NSLinkAttributeName. There're lots of tutorials and Stackoverflow questions about that. You can also read Apple's documentation about attributed string
TextView is the onlycomponent able to open links. So just replace your label with that and :

```
let string              = "A great link : Google"
let range               = (string as NSString).rangeOfString("Google")
let attributedString    = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)

attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: NSURL("http://www.google.fr")!, range: range)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSNumber(int: 1), range: range)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.orangeColor(), range: range)


textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: I've managed to underline the text. How can i make this section of text clickable?

Comment: That makes it a link. I would like this link to be opened in safari

Comment: I replaced string URL by NSURL. If your textview is selectable it should works. Please upvote. Thx

Comment: got an error needing `fileURLWithPath` added this after NSURL still does not open

Comment: Pierre, Great answer. Do you perhaps know how to instead of making the clickable text open a link, but rather just trigger a function ?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
Please create one UILabel & check it's properties. 
Please select Text on first changed it's to plain to Attributed.

    Now you can seen you label text in one Textfield. select that text & right click to you mouse & goto Font menu. you can seen Underline. select it. you can seen underline in your Label.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this also if you want to achieve only half part of label as underline:-

**For Swift 4.0+**

```
let attributesForUnderLine: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont(name: AppFont.sourceSansPro_Regular, size: 12) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
            .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]

        let attributesForNormalText: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont(name: AppFont.sourceSansPro_Regular, size: 12) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11),
            .foregroundColor: AppColors.ColorText_787878]

        let textToSet = "Want to change your preferences? Edit Now"
        let rangeOfUnderLine = (textToSet as NSString).range(of: "Edit Now")
        let rangeOfNormalText = (textToSet as NSString).range(of: "Want to change your preferences?")

        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textToSet)
        attributedText.addAttributes(attributesForUnderLine, range: rangeOfUnderLine)
        attributedText.addAttributes(attributesForNormalText, range: rangeOfNormalText)
        yourLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift3.0

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

  let linkAttributes = [
        NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "http://stalwartitsolution.co.in/luminutri_flow/terms-condition")!
        ] as [String : Any]
  let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Please tick box to confirm you agree to our Terms & Conditions, Privacy Policy, Disclaimer. ")

  attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(44, 18))

  attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSNumber(value: 1), range: NSMakeRange(44, 18))

  textview.delegate = self
  textview.attributedText = attributedString
  textview.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red]
  textview.textColor = UIColor.white
  }


  func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    return true
   }
```