# How to just add underline below the second line of text in a Bar Button Item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I'm thinking about having two separate attributed strings and combine them together. Not sure if this is the only way?

**UPDATE**

The button displays "(null)" if using setAttributedTitle. It can display the right string with no attributes if using setTitle.

**Still cannot display in the intended way. Any idea?**

```
// Set current bar button attributes
NSMutableAttributedString *currentBarAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[currentBarAttributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"REQUEST\n"
                                                                         attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)}]];
[currentBarAttributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"EQUIPMENT"
                                                                                   attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}]];
// Initialize buttons and set titles
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 setAttributedTitle:currentBarAttributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// [button1 setTitle:[currentBarAttributedString string] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053334/how-to-underline-a-uilabel-in-swift

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Please see the update. Any idea?

Comment: when i do NSLog. data is printing.REQUEST
EQUIPMENT

Comment: @ChenyaZhang what problem are you facing now? Is the string not getting formatted, or you cannot see a string at all?

Comment: Change the button type to 'UIButtonTypeSystem' and then try

Comment: @ChenyaZhang instead of doing
`NSMutableAttributedString *currentBarAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];`
Initialize the string like this
`NSMutableAttributedString *currentBarAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];`
Please check this and then let us know if it works or not

Comment: @ShayanJalil The attributed string can be logged out as string correctly. But it displays as (null) on screen.

Comment: @ShayanJalil Yes Shayan, after using "NSMutableAttributedString *currentBarAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];". It is still "(null)".

Comment: @KrutarthPatel It cannot display the string with underline on screen. It shows as "(null)" on screen. Do you think there is anything wrong with the way I set the attributed string?

Comment: @ChenyaZhang Please check my answer.may you got your solution.

Comment: @ChenyaZhang did you got solution?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel I use NSAttributedString and NSMakeRange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add border to text or to change color.here is sample code which is used.
   use This code in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSString *strFirst = @"Request Equipment";
  NSString *strSecond = @"Active Rentals";


NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

[attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strFirst
                                                                         attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle),
                                                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor yellowColor]}]];
[attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strSecond
                                                                         attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone),NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}]];
//To use attribute string in button
[self.btnAttributeString setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

OutPut is

[image]

Please check this and let me know any issue.

Comment: happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a NSAttributedString and format it as required

```
NSString *alertString = @"All heroes do not wear capes.";

NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

NSDictionary *attrs = @{
NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                        //provide a nsdict here with attributes you want to apply to the whole of the string. 
                        };
NSDictionary *subAttrs = @{
                           NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                           //Here provide attributes for the not underlined part of the string. 
                           };
NSDictionary *subAttrs2 = @{
                           NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                           //Here provide attributes for the underlined part of the string
                           };

//Set the range of the sub attributes. 
const NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,3);
const NSRange range2 = NSMakeRange(5,4);

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:alertString
                                       attributes:attrs];
[attributedText setAttributes:subAttrs range:range];
[attributedText setAttributes:subAttrs2 range:range2];
```

Now set this attributed string as your attributed title

Answer (score -1):

```
class UnderlinedLabel: UILabel {

        override var text: String! {

            didSet {
                 let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, count(text))
                let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count)
                let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
                attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName , value:NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: textRange)
                // Add other attributes if needed

                self.attributedText = attributedText
             }
        }
    }
```