# Swift 4.2: [Swift._EmptyArrayStorage _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: swift, nsmutableattributedstring, swift4.2

I'm facing a `NSInvalidArgumentException` exception after upgrading a project to Swift 4.2 (conversion from 4.0).

```
2018-09-19 15:37:33.253482+0100 <redacted>-beta[3715:1010421] -[Swift._EmptyArrayStorage _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107e6c290
2018-09-19 15:37:33.254312+0100 <redacted>-beta[3715:1010421] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._EmptyArrayStorage _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107e6c290'
```

It's something related with a `NSMutableAttributedString` and the code is adding some attributes, for example, a `NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle`.

The exception happens when the attributed string is about to be assigned:  `textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedString`.

---

#### UPDATE:

The code was working in Swift 4:
**`mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue, range: range)`**

But with Swift 4.2, the compiler suggests changing the `NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue` to `NSUnderlineStyle.none.rawValue`

After accepting the change, the compiler started complaining about "*'none' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set*":

```
mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.none.rawValue, range: range)
                                                                                   ^~~~~ 'none' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set
```

Comment: try adding `.rawValue` to your underlineStyle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28054270/2303865

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I just found out what was wrong in the code.

So, because of the compiler error "*'none' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set*", I replaced the **`NSUnderlineStyle.none.rawValue`** with **`[]`** ‍♂️ And that's not the right case because it was using the `rawValue`, not the type `none`.

So, the fix is using **`0`**.

**Wrong:** <strike>`mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: [], range: range)`</strike>

**Right:** `mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 0, range: range)`

Comment: Thanks, saved me a ton of work. Especially since the crash message is not very useful..